# C++ error C2143 syntax error : missing ';' before function name

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I have header file :

```
#ifndef VIP_TICKET_H
#define VIP_TICKET_H

#include "ticket.h"

class VIPTicket : public Ticket
{
public:
    enum VIPType { FIRST_CLASS, FAST_LINE };

    VIPType getTicketType() const;

private:
    VIPType type;
};
#endif
```

and it's cpp file

```
#include "vipTicket.h"

VIPType VIPTicket::getTicketType() const
{
    return type;
}
```

the error says " **error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'VIPTicket::getTicketType'** "

this error is very confusing.. i guess it's not a ';' that is missing but probably something else wrong with the code that I can't put my finger on..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this definition

```
VIPType VIPTicket::getTicketType() const
{
    ...
}
```

When you define this function you have to remember that `VIPType` is not in the global scope, but in the scope of the `VIPTicket` class, so you have to explicitly mention the scope:

```
VIPTicket::VIPType VIPTicket::getTicketType() const
{
    ...
}
```